# How to code a input mask for currency using TextInput in React Native (using Expo)

Tags: react-native, masking

I have an app that makes extensive use of `react-native-paper`'s TextInput. Many of these inputs have to deal with monetary units. I know that TextInput from `react-native-paper` provides a render prop that allows you to add a text input mask and many have already been written. However, I can't seem to find one that works with expo and I only want to eject if absolutely necessary (I like many of the conveniences that expo brings to the table).

Can anyone show me an example of how to use `onChangeText` to accomplish this on my own?

These are my requirements:

1. I want 2 decimal places
2. I want to prevent the user from entering more than 1 decimal (maybe it's better not to allow them to enter a decimal at all - I'll do it once they enter more than 2 digits)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/rnpaper-limit-input)

Of course you can use any regex

Comment: You're example doesn't quite work the way I'm looking for. You only allow one digit when I type it in

Comment: It‘s a sample, you can use any regex.
For example (?!00)\d\d?(\.\d\d?)?